# Conditionally add WHERE statement to PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to conditionally search by date if such string is passed into my method, else no filter by date and all results will return. Pretty simple. I have the following code that is pretty gross, but is currently the only way that I can conceptualize how to add conditionally and still `bindValue`:

```
$qry = "SELECT orderid FROM ".$this->tableName."";
if ($filterFromDate) {
   error_log('----- has filter date');
   $qry .= " WHERE processed > :d";
}
$sth = $this->connection->prepare($qry);
if ($filterFromDate) {
   error_log('----- has filter date');
   $sth->bindValue(":d",$filterFromDate, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sth->execute();       
return $sth->fetchAll();
```

Is there a cleaner approach to this? Secondly, when no date filter is passed in, my query is failing - which can either be due to my gross approach or something deeper here.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable to me. Tell us how it fails when no date filter. BTW, the first statement is concatenating with an empty string to little purpose.

Comment: Alternatively you could use tried and tested solutions like [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb)

Comment: You could keep an array of parameters and then pass this array into the `execute()` which stops it having to bind values individually.  BUT as it stands - it looks as though it would work.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren) suggests, the way you could remove the `if` statement would be to maintain an array of parameters and then pass them into `$sth->exec()`. Something like this should work:

```
$params = [];
$qry = "SELECT orderid FROM ".$this->tableName."";
if ($filterFromDate) {
   error_log('----- has filter date');    
   $qry .= " WHERE processed > ?";
   $params[] = $filterFromDate;
}
$sth = $this->connection->prepare($qry);

$sth->execute($params);       
return $sth->fetchAll();
```

That said, this definitely counts a micro-optimization, so if you find it more readable, your original code is not bad.

Comment: We do this a lot for dynamic queries, you can also use a similar approach to deal with the classic 'bind params in mysql where in (...' problem

Answer (score -1):

Consider one single query that can handle a `NULL` parameter using `COALESCE` on a very early date.

```
// INITIALIZE AS NULL ENTITY
$filterFromDate = null; 
...

// RUN REGARDLESS OF VARIABLE STATE
$qry = "SELECT orderid FROM ".$this->tableName
       ."WHERE processed > COALESCE(:d, '1900-01-01')";

$sth = $this->connection->prepare($qry);
$sth->bindValue(":d", $filterFromDate, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();       
return $sth->fetchAll();
```